# How to exclude the height of hidden divs when obtaining $(document).height();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery mis-calculating the space at the bottom of a page that I am working on. It may well be due to the hidden div layers which are on the page.

Is there a way that jQuery can calculate the 'real' height of the page, as visible in the browser?  Here's my code so far:

```
var doc_height = $(document).height();
var footerHeight = $('.footer-wrapper').height();
var main_body_height = doc_height - footerHeight;
$("div.wrapper-holder").height(main_body_height);
```

This exact code seems to be working fine on other pages of the site, does anyone know what could be causing the problem on this page?

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Screenshot]

A link to the real page is here: http://www.upreach.org.uk/undergraduates/partners.php

Many thanks for any help that you can give...

Comment: Are you looking for the scrolling height of the document or the height of the viewport?

Comment: I think the scrolling height of the whole document, minus the div layers which are hidden.

Comment: Heh, if you resize the window, it works.

Comment: What are you using to hide your divs? display or visibility?

Answer (score 4):

Try running your code (again) on `$(window).on('load')` -- your calculations are probably being upset because the images aren't loaded when `$(document).ready()` is triggered.

A better solution -- and one that won't require you to wait -- is to add `height` attributes to each and every one of your images. (Currently you only set the `width` attribute.) This will have the same result: jQuery will be able to accurately compute the height of the entire document, whether the images are loaded or not.

Comment: Thanks for this @Blazemonger Just to check... should I wrap my code within `$(window).on('load')` and try from there?

Comment: It's not the *best* solution, but it would be the quicker change.